# LaTeX in matplotlib: variable subscripts defined by .format()

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am making an array of subplots where each item is defined in a for loop. For each subplot, the `ylabel` is written in LaTeX as the name of a variable (say `\theta`) with a subindex defined by the counter in the loop. The command `.format()` written inside the `plt.ylabel(r'$\theta_{:2d}$'.format(i))` allows one to specify the index.

However, when the counter has more than 1 digit, the subscript of the variable in the `ylabel` only applies to the first digit and the remaining ones are written inline. Is there something I am mising in the usage of the `.format()`? Or is there another way to fix this?

An example:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 22})
matplotlib.rc('font', **{'family': 'serif', 'serif': ['Computer Modern']})
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

N     = 500
theta = np.random.randn(90,N)
idx   = np.array([4,24,64,89])
nplot = len(idx) 

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nplot, 1, sharex='col', figsize=(10, 5))
axes      = axes.flatten()
for i in range(nplot):
    ax = axes[i]
    ax.plot(theta[idx[i],:], '-', color='navy')
    ax.set_ylabel(r'$\theta_{:2d}$'.format(idx[i]+1))
    ax.set_xlim([0,N])
plt.show()
```

The resulting figure showing the issue looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the formatting to this:

```py
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\theta_{{{:2d}}}$'.format(idx[i]+1))
```

LaTeX expects the formatting to be `\theta_{somenumber}`, otherwise it will only subscript the first digit. To achieve this, you need 3 brackets in Python.

Comment: I tried with 2 brackets and it did not work, never thought python required 3. Thank you !